# Citations not working

Tags: bibliographies

I've read every tutorial on citations and tried with `biber` and others but when I compile the cite doesn't show up here is a snippet of my code.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=1in, outer=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\section{Results}
\cite{house2003english}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sources.bib}
\section{Conclusion}
\section{Evaluation}
\onecolumn
\section{Bibliography}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\end{document}
```

I have no citation packages imported

[image]

My bib file is in the same folder as my tex file and I have made sure my spelling is correct. Here is my bib file:

```
@article{house2003english,
  title={English as lingua franca and its influence on discourse norms in other languages},
  author={House, Juliane},
  journal={Translation today: Trends and perspectives},
  pages={168--180},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Clevedon: Multilingual Matters}
}
```

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the standard compilation cycle: LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX? Please clarify what you mean by "tried with biber and others".

Comment: Please give us a minimum working example (MWE).  That is a cut-down file beginning with ```\documentclass```, ```\usepackage{bibtex}``` (if that is what you are using, etc.

Comment: updated the code with the cut-down file
I have tried the standard compilation cycle 
I followed along with this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwXQb25cpqA and didn't use \usepackage{bibtex} I have used tutorials with \usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex} from this tutorial https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_biblatex

Comment: Please post not just some code snippets but an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: the code that I copied is a MWE, it outputs the same probelm that i have https://imgur.com/a/cDuBPfm

Answer (score 0):

Your next step is to run bibtex;  then run pdflatex (or whatever) twice.

Comment: I ran bibtex on the tex file and got this 
`
Process started

I couldn't open file name `build/Physics IA.aux'

Process exited normally
`

then i ran pdflatex twice but still the same results
pdflatex error says 
`
Citation 'house2003english' on page 1 undefined
`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, the problem was that there was a space in my directory folder that `sources.bib` was in. I changed from "Physics IA" to "PhysicsIA" next I used a direct path:

`\bibliography{C://Users/Alex/Desktop/PhysicsIA/sources.bib}`

then it worked